# .click/ is:checked not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I got this function opening a div is my checkbox is checked but is not working on chrome, and it work on ie8/9, firefox, opera and safari. Any idea why this?

```
$('#checkbox-01').click(function () {
    if ($('#checkbox-01').is(':checked')) {
        $('.box').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.square').hide('fast');
    } else {
        $('.box').fadeOut('fast');
        $('.square').hide('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: use `this.checked` instead of `$('#checkbox-01').is(':checked')`

Comment: Code works in chrome, see fiddlediddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LNph3/

Comment: Checked or not checked, `$('.square')` div is always hidden, as per your code. You can put that code outside the click function!

Comment: it shows and dsappear right away...

Comment: actually the 'else' is triggering at the same time, any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Use that function:

```
$('#checkbox-01').change(function (){    
if(this.checked) {
    $('.box').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.square').hide('fast');
}else{
    $('.box').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.square').hide('fast');
}
});
```

Comment: the same man, the thing shows and disappear, i can't figure out why it's happening just in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
$('#checkbox-01').click(function () {
if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
    $('.box').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.square').hide('fast');
} else {
    $('.box').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.square').hide('fast');
}
});
```